# org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 103 of

Tags: java, android, json

i don't know  why this strings contert to Json have error.

```
{
  softName: lovePlay,
  packageName: com.feng.play,
  softId:13232,
  downUrl: http.//mumayi.pay.love/down?id=13211
}
```

Have somebody can help me? thanks.

Comment: this is an invalid json

Comment: current string is not valid to convert as jsonpbject. u will need to change your server side code for returning valid Json String

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK +1 for sure yes :)) once again i remove answer, too late... :-

Comment: thanks all. I have solved this problem。 it ok like this           <input type="button" onclick="getp1('{softName:lovePlay,packageName:com.feng.play,softId:13232,downUrl:\'http\:\/\/mumayi.pay.love\/down\?id=13211\'}')" value="获取"/>

Comment: if this string is get from object.toString(); change this and get from gson function.

Answer (score 8):

Strings should be under double quotes. Something like this:

```
{
   "softName":"lovePlay",
   "packageName":"com.feng.play",
   "softId":13232,
   "downUrl":"http.//mumayi.pay.love/down?id=13211"
}
```

There are many services on the internet where you be able to validate your json data. 
Click [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: i konw this is error,but it use at html. ex:onclick="getp1('{softName:lovePlay,packageName:com.feng.play,softId:13232,downUrl:http\:\/\/mumayi.pay.love\/down\?id=13211}')"             when i didn't write downUrl:http......, it can convert to json

Comment: you have to escape double quotes like following:
`onclick="getp1('{\"softName\":\"lovePlay\", \"packageName\":\"com.feng.play\", \"softId\":13232, \"downUrl\":\"http://www.google.com\"}')"`

Comment: thanks. I have solved this problem。 it's ok like this           <input type="button" onclick="getp1('{softName:lovePlay,packageName:com.feng.play,softId:13232,downUrl:\'http\:\/\/mumayi.pay.love\/down\?id=13211\'}')" value="获取"/>

Comment: how to insert double quotes if I'm getting the same json as shown in question?

Answer (score 3):

Your `JSON` string is incorrect, you're missing the quote signs (`"`).

Try this:

```
{
    "softName": "lovePlay",
    "packageName": "com.feng.play",
    "softId": "13232",
    "downUrl": "http.//mumayi.pay.love/down?id=13211"
}
```

Comment: i konw this is error,but it use at html. ex:onclick="getp1('{softName:lovePlay,packageName:com.feng.play,softId:13232,dow‌​nUrl:http\:\/\/mumayi.pay.love\/down\?id=13211}')" when i didn't write downUrl:http......, it can convert to json

Comment: thanks. I have solved this problem。 it's ok like this           <input type="button" onclick="getp1('{softName:lovePlay,packageName:com.feng.play,softId:13232,downUrl:\'http\:\/\/mumayi.pay.love\/down\?id=13211\'}')" value="获取"/>

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in your JSON string. You need to change it as below.

```
{
    "softName": "lovePlay",
    "packageName": "com.feng.play",
    "softId": "13232",
    "downUrl": "http.//mumayi.pay.love/down?id=13211"
}
```

If you are on web dev environment you can use stringify command. Check out this tutorial on [JSON and Java](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html)

As a good practice, check whether your JSON is valid. There are many tools available but [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) is my favourite.

Comment: thanks. I have solved this problem。 it's ok like this           <input type="button" onclick="getp1('{softName:lovePlay,packageName:com.feng.play,softId:13232,downUrl:\'http\:\/\/mumayi.pay.love\/down\?id=13211\'}')" value="获取"/>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all. I have solved this problem. When I use this:

```
<!-- white space added for readability -->
<input type="button" onclick="getp1('{softName:lovePlay
             ,packageName:com.feng.play
             ,softId:13232
             ,downUrl:\'http\:\/\/mumayi.pay.love\/down\?id=13211\'}')" 
            value="获取"/>
```

I can get strings convert to json.  I use it by webview.

Answer (score 1):

This is my method currently using

```
public String convertStandardJSONString(String data_json){
    data_json = data_json.replace("\\", "");
    data_json = data_json.replace("\"{", "{");
    data_json = data_json.replace("}\",", "},");
    data_json = data_json.replace("}\"", "}");
    return data_json;
}
```